# How to call a function inside $(document).ready

Tags: jquery, debugging, firebug

Im trying to debug my web app that uses `jQuery.`

In firebug im calling functions inside the $(document).ready..

```
 function val() { console.log('validated outside doc.ready'); }
 $(document).ready(function()
 {

    console.log('document ready...');

    function validate() { console.log('validated!'); }
 }
```

In firebug console I type `validate()` and it says its not a function

If i type `val()` it works fine.

How do i call validate from the console ?

Comment: why don't you put your validation function outside the document.ready function.. the issue is your function is out of scope when it is called..

Comment: it is because `validate` is a closure function within the anonymus function passed to `ready` as callback

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You are not calling a function like that, you just **define** the function.

The correct approach is to define the function outside `document.ready` and call it inside:

```
// We define the function
function validate(){
  console.log('validated!');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  // we call the function
  validate();
});
```

Another option is to **self invoke** the function like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // we define and invoke a function
   (function(){
     console.log('validated!');
   })();
});
```

Comment: Yes I like this way, very clean and thank you very much. Ive only been using jQuery seriously for the last few months so Im learning heaps cheers :)

Answer (score 12):

Your `validate` function is local to the function you've passed to the jQuery `ready` handler.

if you do:

```
window.validate = function(){ /*....*/ };
```

you will be able to access from console. But it's not good practice to pollute the global scope unless it's just for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

well, is there any reason you'd need that function inside document ready? 
only inside those brackets (scope) the function will exist. just move it out, or all it only inside document.ready

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 mistakes in your code.

1. Format to close bracket
2. You aren't calling the function. Calling the function is required to print it.

```html
<script>
  function val() { console.log('validated outside doc.ready'); }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('document ready...');
    validate();
    function validate() { val();  console.log('validated!'); }
  });
</script>
```