# $(document).ready(function () unable to call function in controller

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, datatable

I am using data table to display large number of rows from database.I was using below code to display data fetched from database but as data started increasing,it takes lots of time to load as there are multiple joins in select query.

Below is the code which takes lots of time to load view:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#fileData').dataTable({
                    "aLengthMenu": [[5,10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],   
                    //"aaSorting": [[ 4, "desc" ]], 
                    "iDisplayLength": <?php echo 5; ?>, 
                    'bProcessing'    : true,
                    'bServerSide'    : false,
                    "oTableTools": {
                        "sSwfPath": "assets/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                        "aButtons": []
                    },
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sSearch": "Filter: "
                    },  
                    "aoColumns": [ 
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                    ],
                    "aoColumns": [
                        {"bVisible": true},
                        {"bVisible": true},
                        {"bVisible": true},
                        {"bVisible": true},
                        {"bVisible": true},
                        {"bVisible": true},
                        {"bVisible": true},
                        {"bVisible": true},
                        {"bVisible": true},
                        {"bVisible": true},
                                        {"bVisible": true}
                    ]   
                }).columnFilter({ aoColumns: [
                    { type: "text", bRegex:true },
                    { type: "text", bRegex:true },
                    { type: "text", bRegex:true },
                    { type: "text", bRegex:true },
                    { type: "text", bRegex:true },
                    { type: "text", bRegex:true },
                    { type: "text", bRegex:true },
                    { type: "text", bRegex:true },
                    { type: "text", bRegex:true },
                    { type: "text", bRegex:true },
                                { type: "text", bRegex:true }
                ]});
            });
    </script>
    <table id="fileData" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Sl.No</th>
                                                <th>Type</th>
                                                <th>No </th>
                                                <th>0-15 yrs M</th>
                                                <th>0-15 yrs F</th>
                                                <th>15-45 yrs M</th>
                                                <th>15-45 yrs F</th>
                                                <th>Above 45 yrs M</th>
                                                <th>Above 45 yrs F</th>
                                                                                            <th>Cumulative Since April</th>
                                                <th>Remarks</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        <?php //if(is_object($proj_workers_report)) {  
                                        ?>
                                            <?php foreach ($nreports->result() as $index=>$row) { ?>
                                                <tr> 
                                                            <td> <?php echo $index + 1; ?> </td>
                                                            <td><?php echo $row->test1; ?></td>
                                                            <td><?php echo $row->test2; ?></td>
                                                            <td><?php echo $row->test3; ?></td>
                                                            <td><?php echo $row->test4; ?></td>
                                                            <td><?php echo $row->test5; ?></td>
                                                            <td><?php echo $row->test; ?></td>

                                                              </td>
                                                            <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            <?php
                                            } ?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
After searching for solution to reduce loading time i found solution as enabling "serverSide":true.so i changed the code as below

$(document).ready(function () {
        var year="<?php echo base_url() . 'reportc/new_disease_morbidity_report'; ?>";
        alert(year);
        var dataTable = $('#example2').DataTable({  
          "processing":true,  
          "serverSide":true,  
          "order":[[ 0, "desc" ]],  
          "ajax":{  
        url:"<?php echo base_url() . 'test/nreport'; ?>",   
        type:"POST",
        data:"{'id':year}",
        success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        },  
        'language': {
                "emptyTable":"No patient available"
            },
        "columnDefs":[  
        {  
        //"targets":[0, 3],  
        //"orderable":false,  
        },  
          ],  
         });  
        controller:
        function new_disease_morbidity_report()
            {
                $year = $this->input->post('id');
                echo $year; 
        }
```

But issue with new code is that it is unable to call function in controller.can anyone help me out with this issue.Is there something i am missing ?

Comment: See please here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17567235/5193536

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function inside $(document).ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567176/how-to-call-a-function-inside-document-ready)

Comment: how many rows are in table datatable can render 50000 records easily at a time

Comment: first of all check how many rows are returning using your api

Comment: "unable to call function" in what way?  What's the error or specific failure you're observing?  You're showing a lot of code in a fairly disjointed post.  The description of the second code snippet implies that it's working?  What is the exact problem you're trying to describe?

Comment: with 1st code issue is that it takes lots of time to load data as there are 10 joins to the select query.so went on to use 2nd code but there the issue is its not calling function mentioned in url in ajax.

Comment: @Nisha: What is the resulting URL emitted by `"<?php echo base_url() . 'test/nreport'; ?>"` ?  In your browser's debugging tools, what is the URL of the AJAX request being made?  What is the server's response?  Is the request being made at all?  Is there any error in the browser's development console?

Answer (score 0):

Just by adding  `"serverSide": true` you are telling Datatable **let me handle Pagination**

In order to do so Datatable will append few request parameter in request API and in response you need to set few parameter to let Server Side pagination work smoothly.

You are on right track. Just need to implement correctly.

**Note:** As Datatable will append few parameter you need to handle them at your controller level. Add those parameters as `@RequestParam`. Inspect your API call to get exact parameters.

1 Datatable will add following parameter in your request `POST/GET`

```
    order:  asc
    start:  20
    length: 10
```

This will help you in passing LIMIT parameter in DB Query.

```
SELECT * FROM User LIMIT 20,10;
```

2  Your API should return following fields in addition

```
"draw": 3,             // unique ID
"recordsTotal": 57,    // total number of records
"recordsFiltered": 57  // total number of filtered records
```

You can see a sample demo [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) Please inspect and check request and response

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51881222/datatables-server-side-pagination/51881687#51881687) for more detail.

Comment: I have changed my code according to the link but still unable to call function in controller.do i need to include some scripts in heading ?i am using below two <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/plugins/jQuery-lib/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/plugins/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

Comment: Please add your controller and what URL is being fired from UI when you add server side true

Comment: This the URL: http://localhost/sunproject_master/reportc/new_disease_morbidity_report

Comment: Controller:function new_disease_morbidity_report(){
$this->load->model('reportm_test');
$get_refered_patients=$this->reportm_test->GetPatientsDetail();
$data = array();  
$sub_array = array();
foreach($get_refered_patients as $row){ 
$sub_array[] = $row->name;  
$sub_array[] = $row->unit_id;  
$data[] = $sub_array;}  
$output = array(  
"draw"=>intval($_POST["draw"]),  
"recordsTotal"=>$this->reportm_test->GetAllPatientsDetail_data(),  
"recordsFiltered"=>$this->reportm_test->GetPatientsDetailFiltered_data(),  
"data"=>$data);  
echo json_encode($output);}